# Mysql Multilingual Database design and Query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm building a database for my new website. In this database I have to store articles, article images, and article tags. All this must be with multilanguage support. After some research on the internet, I tried to build something like this:

[image]

I ask you if there is a better way to do this, and how I could get, for example, all the infos about one article in german, with one query (article_title, author, language_name, date_created, all the tags for the article, all the images for the article)

I tried something like this to get title, text, and language name

```
SELECT  t.article_title, t.article_text, l.language_name
FROM 
    `articles` a
        INNER JOIN `articles_t` t ON a.article_id = t.article_id
        INNER JOIN `languages` l ON t.language_code = l.language_code

WHERE a.article_id = 1 AND l.language_code="it-IT"
```